# HTML no ejecuta mi Script

Tags: javascript, html, express

Tengo estos tres archivos:
Código html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lag="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Título</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <input type="button" id="btn" value="Presiona">
        <p id="miP">Mi parrafo</p>
        <script src="scripts.js"></script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Código javascript:

```
(function() {
    var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
    var miP = document.getElementById("miP");

    const inner = function () {
        miP.innerHTML = "Hola!";
    }
    btn.addEventListener("click", inner);
}());
```

Código express:

```
const express = require('express'),
        path = require('path'),
        app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.port || 3000);

app.get("/probando", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/pag.html'));
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server express escuchando el puerto ${app.get('port')}`);
})
```

Cuando ingreso a la url "/probando" en mi local host no me carga el archivo js. Pero cuando ingreso directamente desde la carpeta al archivo html sí se carga el js. ¿Alguien podría identificar el error?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas especificar una ruta pública, usando:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```

Y tu código se vería así:

```
const express = require('express'),
        path = require('path'),
        app = express();

app.set('port', process.env.port || 3000);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))) // <-- ruta pública
app.get("/probando", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/pag.html'));
})

app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log(`Server express escuchando el puerto ${app.get('port')}`);
})
```

Después crea una carpeta llamada **`public`** y ahí guarda tu archivo `script.js` pero sin modifica tu html

Comment: Este código es sencillo, pero en un proyecto que utilizo para practicar lo tengo tal cual me decís vos, y aún así tengo el error. Mis archivos css, img y scripts están en una carpeta pública, y desde mi app.js establezco esa carpeta como archivos estáticos con ese método app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')). Los archivos css me los ejecuta, pero los scripts no :(

Comment: Quizás el problema sea en la ruta de la etiqueta Script. En este código de ejemplo, si tuviera una carpeta pública con mi archivo "scripts.js", la ruta del html toma como raíz la carpeta public?

Comment: Si, y seria `/scripts.js` en el atributo `src` de tu etiqueta `script`